# Vue.js: How to call method from another exported constent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am exporting set of constants and using it as mixin. I am not sure how to call methods from different exported constant?

mixins.js

```
export const exConstOne = {
  methods: {
    fnOne () {
      console.log('exConstOne > fnOne got fired')
    }
  }
}

export const exConstTwo = {
  methods: {
    fnTwo () {
      exConstOne.fnOne()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fnTwo()
  }
}
```

MyComponent.vue

```
<script>
  import { exConstTwo } from './mixins'

  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    mixins: [exConstTwo],
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You could pass the function as a parameter: `fnTwo (fn) { fn(); }` and instead of using mounted inside the mixin, use the mounted within the component. Alternatively, mixins are just objects so you should be able to import `exConstOne` in `exConstTwo` and do `exConstOne.methods.fnOne()`

Comment: Looks like exConstTwo should use exConstOne via mixin ( mixins: [exConstOne ]) and fnTwo method should be  (fnTwo(){ this.fnOne()})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot the "methods" in your function call.**

If you change your code for the following it will work

mixin.js

```
export const exConstOne = {
  methods: {
    fnOne () {
      console.log('exConstOne > fnOne got fired')
    }
  }
}

export const exConstTwo = {
  methods: {
    fnTwo () {
      exConstOne.methods.fnOne()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fnTwo()
  }
}
```

**Note**: The issue is not really Vue related. It's just a javascript mistake.

Comment: I did not forgot to add `methods` but in vue.js, there is mechanism set in such a way that there is no need to use `methods` and I trying to figure that out.

Comment: @Syed Indeed when using mixins you don't need "methods" but it's not what we are talking about here. When your object "exConstOne" is used by "exConstTwo", you need to use "methods" because this code has nothing to do with Vue. It's just 2 plains javascript objects.